# ASP.NET MVC Razor form to EF Create form with file upload

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I've found numerous simple examples of uploading a file using an MVC Razor view and associated controller method but nine that include paying an EF model as well as the file back to the controller. Can anyone help with resources they have or have found?

Comment: It sounds like he wants to post a file along with some EF model data from his view at the same time. Can't you just create a model that contains both the file and your EF model and post that? Something similar to [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/aX9D090113-File-upload-with-strongly-typed-view-and-model-validation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult SomeControllerFunction(EFModel model, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
```

where you have a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeControllerFunction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //various fields for the EF model, plus
     <input type="file" name="ImageFile" id="ImageFile" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include a property in your view model:

```
class MyViewModel {
    public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

Add the file input to your form:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" />
```

Then the file will come in through your model:

```
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model) {

    //model.MyFile will be myFile
}
```

Comment: Maybe I just had a different reading, but it sounded like he wanted to pass not only the file, but also some additional data along with the file.

Comment: Which he can do, I just can't add the additional data without any context. This is just the absolute basic way to post a file to a controller.

Comment: Oh, agreed, but the OP already stated that he found multiple examples of just uploading a file.